# App domain and AssemblyResolve event when using Creator

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

I registered to AssemblyResolve and also to ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve, but when i run my code i dont get any of those events.
I think the issue us that i am using Activator to build the object.

My code:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += LoadFromSameFolder;
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve += LoadFromSameFolder;

 var t = Activator.CreateInstance(myType,myobject);
```

There are assemblies that want to load in run time and I expect to get event when assembly is missing, but events dont come.. instead i get FileNotFound Exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\MyFile.dll' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Any idea??

Comment: Your problem is not the Activator. The AssemblyResolve event handler is invoked when I tried to reproduce your problem. You should check the fusion logs. Can you please add the values of myType and myObject?

Comment: Are you trying to pass in the assembly path to Activator.CreateInstance ?

Comment: Don't understand your problem - if you can pass myType - you already have assembly loaded. Where we can catch AssemblyResolve fired? Your code not contains any cause to dynamically assembly loading. For example it could be `var myType = Type.GetType("My.MyType, mylib.dll")` or something similar.

Comment: MyType is from other dll. i load this dll fine, the FileNotFound Exception is thrown on dll that referenced in MyType related dll. more of that: even when i load the dependency dll but from other path, i still get the file not found since it looks for him in MyType related dll